# Loading and Cleaning the Data

Tags: pandas, python-2.7

How to remove sign `$` in columns?

```
import pandas as pd
sales= pd.read_csv("Gadget_Sales.csv")
sales['LastSpend'] = sales['LastSpend'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip('$-'))
```

I tried the above code, which removes the `$` sign. The resulting data structure contains strings, but I want them as integers so I can perform multiplication on them.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `float(x.lstrip('$'))` in the lambda will cast the elements to a `float` datatype. I have removed the `-` from the `lstrip()` so that values that are negative remain so

E.g.

```
# Assuming sales['LastSpend'] = ["$12.34", "$-56.78"]
sales['LastSpend'] = list(map(lambda x: float(x.lstrip('$')), sales['LastSpend']))
print(sales['LastSpend'])
# [12.34, -56.78]

# Assuming sales['LastSpend'] = "$-12.34"
sales['LastSpend'] = float(sales['LastSpend'].lstrip('$'))
print(sales['LastSpend'])
# -12.34
```

Comment: Please could you remove dollar sign using  def remove_dollar  method